# Trying to create a !say command in my discord.py rewrite bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm using discord.py rewrite and want to create a command that spits back the text that comes after the command, "$say." I looked on the docs and online but couldn't find any up-to-date code. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use a command make sure to import commands and than create an context parameter. Like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, message=None)
    await ctx.send(message)

bot.run("TOKEN HERE")
```

This command would be executed by `$say message` because when we defined bot we set the prefix and when we set the command we did `async def name` and obviously our command name is say.

So in discord when your bot is running you could do `$say good morning!` and the bot will reply in that channel with `good morning!`.

ctx.send is a coroutine which is why we did await in front of it. And ctx defines the channel while message is our message parameter.

Some helpful resources:

- Docs: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- [Discord.py FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)
- [discord.py GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)
- [discord.py Discord](https://discord.gg/dpy)

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, question):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f'{question}')
```

I send this only because you can use this and have it delete the authors message. Then it also sends any type of message after your command.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have a say command that only works with the user id specified.

```
async def speak(ctx, *, text):
    if ctx.message.author.id == 621102107621326878:
        message = ctx.message
        await message.delete()

        await ctx.send(f"{text}")
    else:
        await ctx.send('lol mate what u doin that isn\'t a real command')
```

If you would like a normal one, do this:

```
async def speak(ctx, *, text):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()

    await ctx.send(f"{text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is what I use

```
@client.command
async def say(ctx, *, text=''):
    if text == '':
        ctx.send("You need to say something")
    else:
        ctx.send(text)
        ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

the most simple code that i've wrote is

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    try:
        await ctx.send(message)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Please Give Some Message!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put * between ctx and message=None. message=None will watch the message after the command.

Me I’m using this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx,*,message=None)
  await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command
async def say(ctx, *, text=''):
if text == '':
    ctx.send("Say Something First Noob!")
else:
await ctx.send(text)
```

Now Notice That Dont Do ctx.send Have await before ctx if u will not then 100% it will say it was never awaited

Answer (score 0):

Here!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await ctx.send(message)

client.run("YOUR_TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an infinite arg

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message=None):
    if message == None:
        await ctx.send('Provide some message')
    else:
        await ctx.send(message)
```